# How to override chef apache2 default-site template?

Tags: chef-infra

In chef apache2 cookbook you can find attribute `node['apache']['default_site_enabled']` that is enabling default site. If you set to true then this template is use  `apache2/templates/default/default-site.erb`. But what I found there is fixed value `AllowOverride None`, so obviously you can't change it via attribute. So my question is how can I override it in my custom cookbook so I can tweak this template in my very own way?

Or maybe there is other better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your own cookbook that wraps this apache2 cookbook, let's call it apache2_wrap. Create your own *apache2_wrap/templates/default/default-site.erb* template and set the values there the way you need it to be. Your recipe should look like that:

```
include_recipe 'apache2::default' #or whatever apache2 recipe you need

#enable default site yourself
template "#{node['apache']['dir']}/sites-available/default" do
  source   'default-site.erb'
  owner    'root'
  group    node['apache']['root_group']
  mode     '0644'
  notifies :restart, 'service[apache2]'
end

apache_site 'default' do
  enable true
end
```

I did not test it, but it should work. There is 1 potential problem however: looks like this `"#{node['apache']['dir']}/sites-available/default"` file will be overwritten every time the chef is run, first with original template, then by yours. Which launches apache2 restart trigger and thus apache2 service will be restarted every chef run (but I am not sure - you should test it!). If that is the case and it bothers you, then the only way is to create your own cookbook based on existing cookbook.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figure out after some time.